# Adjusting lines of text around a drop cap?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I am using a drop cap that spans two lines of text in a paragraph, and would like to adjust the text of the paragraph rows around it.

For example, if the drop cap is an "A", I'd like to move the first row a bit closer (to the left) to the top of the "A"
and move the second row a bit further (to the right) from the bottom of the "A".

I do this in CSS by setting the margin on the drop cap that suits the second row and then placing a negative margin on the first row, but don't see a method of doing so in LibreOffice. Is there one?

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Without a Drop Cap, you may select two adjacent characters and use
`Menu: Format > Character > Position` > Character spacing: *number* **[v] Pair kerning**
to adjust the "distance" between them.

But then, Drop Cap seems to 'disable' that...